# REST request and JSON Response

Tags: android, json, rest, parsing

Resource URL    http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/

Request Method  REST (GET)

Response Format JSON

Response Encoding   UTF-8

how to create a android library to handle the requests and parsing of responses  ?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create the POJO classes according to your JSON response. Also suggest you to use the Spring REST Client [REST CLIENT](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) Or if you want your own lib then use the Jackson libraries for easy POJO class handling and.